# Wildfly domain configuration - multiple servers on one host?

Tags: wildfly

Exactly what is the significance of server-one, server-two, and server-three in domain configuration? Why is there more then one in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of a managed domain is to have a central management point for all WildFly servers in your domain. This means if you need to make a configuration change across all servers in your domain you only need make the change once instead of having to connect to multiple servers to make a change.

See the [operating modes](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY/Operating+modes) documentation to see more details about it.

Comment: so from what I gather server-one, server-two and server-three are basically separate Wildfly instances managed by the same host controller?

Comment: Servers belong to server groups. By default server-one and server-two belong to main-server-group and server-three belongs to other-server-group. All profiles and server groups belong to the same host controller.